# mobx: determine that data are added (deleted or modified) to the storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

there is storage for the component:

```
class BaseStorage {

                private m_owner: BasePageReports | undefined = undefined;
    @observable private m_apply: boolean = false;

    constructor(owner: BasePageReports) {

        this.m_owner = owner;

        reaction(
            () => this.m_apply,
            (enabled: boolean) => {
                if (enabled === true)
                {
                    this.m_apply = false;

                    if (this.m_owner !== undefined)
                        this.m_owner["start"](this);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    apply(): void {
        this.m_apply = true;
    }
}
```

storages for components are contained in the main component (page)

```
@observer class BasePageReports extends Component {

    private m_stores: Array<BaseFilterStorage> = [];

    start(store: BaseFilterStorage): void {
        console.log(store);
    }
}
```

data is added to the storages in the child components:

for example:

```
handleMultiselect = (data: any) => {
    this.props.store[this.state.field] = data;
}
```

component (the Apply button) functions like this:

```
handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    this.props.store.apply();
}
```

**Question:**

I want the Apply button to be active or inactive, depending on the result of data analysis in the repository (for example, the data should not be empty):

```
    render() {

        return (
<div className = 'element-apply'>
    <button disabled = {this.props.store.check()} onClick = {this.handleClick}>Apply</button>
</div>
        );
    }
```

but how to implement the `check()` function so that it is called every time the data in the storage is changed